# OraOleDB Provider error

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis, connection-string, oledb

I have created a website that has an oracle connection in it that works when I launch it in Visual Web Developer Express. However, when I launch the site from the server on IIS 7, I get 
The 'OraOleDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I am on a 64-bit machine. I have the 64-bit OLE DB Oracle driver installed and registered (using regsvr32 that everyone mentions) as well as security rights for IIS_USERS. My current connection string is below:

> > > add name="TDRP" connectionString="Provider=OraOleDB.Oracle;Data Source=TDRP;Persist Security Info=True;Password=********;User ID=*****; providerName="System.Data.OleDb"

Am I approaching this problem correctly? I saw a number of different formats for connection strings as well as using provider name "system.data.oracleclient" instead of "system.data.oledb." Also, should my data source be .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB or Oracle Database? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your driver installer may not have copied all files needed. If that is the case, you may have to manually copy the missed files. (Ref: http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/07/27/solution-for-oraoledb-oracle-provider-is-not-registered-error/)

Comment: I wish I could say that worked, but I'm still getting the same error :/